# postgres equivilent of oracle sqlplus "set echo on"

Tags: postgresql

Is there an equivalent in PostgreSQL of the Oracle SQLPLUS "set echo on" so that I can get batch input
statements echoed in the output?

I have a very large file with input statements in it that has a few errors when I run it. 
I am having difficulty finding the statement that produced the error because psql is only reporting 
the error - not the statement that generated the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the `-a` (or `--echo-all`) argument to `psql`. It's described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html under OPTIONS.

Comment: ... but, if you don't want to set it at psql time (such as needing to turn it on and off during a script), you can use \set ECHO all (or \set ECHO none).

Answer (score 1):

-- set echo on

```
\set ECHO all
```

-- set echo off

```
\set ECHO none
```

From a list of psql equivalents to sqlplus commands, here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/postgresql-psql-client-tool-commands-equivalent-to-oracle-sqlplus-client-tool/

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL also logs errors in its server logs, along with the statement that caused it. That might be useful to bear in mind for debugging errors with tools other than psql that don't report errors very well.